# How do I put user inputted values into an array?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to put user named values into an array to be used later on. However, I get an infinite loop with my code so far... here's what I got:

```
def dates():
    dates = []
    user_input = raw_input("Please put folder with format yy.mm.dd: ")
    while user_input != 'end':
        if user_input == '%y.%m.%d':
            dates.append(user_input)
        else:
            print "Please out folder in form yy.mm.dd or write 'end'"
    print dates
```

new function:

```
def date():
    dates = []
    user_input =raw_input("Please put folder with format yy.mm.dd: ")
    pattern = re.compile('\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}')
    if pattern.match(user_input):
        dates.append(user_input)
    elif user_input == 'end':
        print 'Dates:'
    else:
        print "Use yy.mm.dd format or write 'end'"

    return dates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code, first:

```
user_input = raw_input("Please put folder with format yy.mm.dd: ")
```

This input is evaluated only once, so either you go to infinite loop, or you add only one string to list.

Moreover,

```
user_input == '%y.%m.%d'
```

This comparision checks for string equality, not for pattern matching. You have two options, first to use regular expression to check validity of input string:

```
pattern = re.compile('\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}')
if pattern.match(user_input):
    pass # handle valid input
else:
    pass # handle invalid input
```

This option has a drawback as you'll be able to pass `00` or `>12` for month, analogically for day bigger than `31` etc.

For me preferred way would be to use EAFP approach and try to create `datetime.date` object.

```
year, month, day = user_input.split('.')
try:
    date = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
except ValueError:
    pass # handle invalid input
else:
    pass # handle valid input
```

Comment: Ok I implemented the first solution, but now I don't know how to get more than one value into dates...? I'm updating my code in the main entry.

Comment: You've had ready solution for looping over user input with `while` loop, I'm not sure why you get rid of it.

Comment: I realized and I put it back!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you never request user input *inside* your `while` loop. As a result, it keeps evaluating your first `user_input`, and your user never has the opportunity to type `'end'` and break out of the loop. Place another `raw_input` call within your `while` loop instead of your `else` string, in order to actually re-evaluate user input. This will ensure that if the format is correct, your user will be cued for another input as well.

Also, since you have a function `dates()`, you should `return` your result if that is the end of your function, not `print` it.

Finally, as your conditional statement currently stands the only valid match you will ever have is the literal string. You need to use regex or an actual pattern match in order to match valid inputs.

Comment: Ok that worked! However, the program is not recognizing, for example, '10.10.10' as a valid input to satisfy the if statement.

Comment: Well, is `10.10.10` equal to `%y.%m.%d`? Obviously not, so of course it won't be considered valid by your `if` statement.